# BIRT, DB2, Adding 1 minute to the end date of a between date parameter

Tags: parameters, timestamp, db2, birt, minute

The following works in Squirrel when substituting a value for "?"

and s.createstamp between ? and ? + 1 MINUTE

The error in BIRT:

SQL error #1: [SQL0184] Parameter marker not valid in expression.

Comment: Maybe Squirrel does the substitution before it runs the statement., when BIRT really uses dynamic SQL statements. If so datetime arithmetics aren't allowed with parameter markers. You have to cast them. Try `between cast(? as timestamp) and cast(? as timestamp) + 1 minute`

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IrdUdKel) link with an example. You have to cast parameter markers to help db2 determine the data types. It doesn't work without such an explicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add the +1 minute in the parameter part of the dataset with a script?
[image]
So after the parameter is set by the user, add +1 minute to that date using javascript